# Adding Jupyter support for VS Code remote into a Dockerfile for a new image

Tags: jupyter-notebook, dockerfile, vscode-extensions

I have an existing Docker image that has Python 3 and PIP installed and other components as well, call it `OriginalImage`.

I am able to connect to `OriginalImage` container from VS Code and then install Jupyter for `DevContainer` then use Jupyter from VS Code remote.

I want to build a new image, `MyImage` on top of `OriginalImage` that is ready for remote connection of Jupyter Notebook from VS Code Remote.

I tried in my `Dockerfile` at add: `FROM jupyter/minimal-notebook` but that didn't work and I think I am still missing the extensions of VS Code.

How do I add support for Jupyter Notebook from VS Code remote to my `Dockerfile`?

Answer (score 0):

I am leveraging vscode devcontainer feature and creating a Dockerfile with the specifics of what I need in the image.
The devcontainer allows you to specify which extensions you will need in the container.
You can control what you want at image level vs what you want the devcontainer to do post.

I am using micromamba and my docker file is configured to read from requirements.txt to install the required packages.

Here example of what I have in my .devcontainer folder inside of the project folder I open with vscode:

`devcontainer.json`

```
// For format details, see https://aka.ms/devcontainer.json. For config options, see the README at:
// https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dev-containers/tree/v0.245.2/containers/jupyter-datascience-notebooks
{
    "build": {
        "dockerfile": "./Dockerfile",
        "context": "."
    },
    "userEnvProbe": "interactiveShell",
    // Forward Jupyter port locally, mark required
    "forwardPorts": [
        8888,
        8787
    ],
    "portsAttributes": {
        "8888": {
            "label": "Jupyter",
            "requireLocalPort": true,
            "onAutoForward": "ignore"
        },
        "8787": {
            "label": "Dask Dashboard",
            "requireLocalPort": true,
            "onAutoForward": "ignore"
        }
    },
    "runArgs": [
        "--userns=keep-id"
    ],
    // Configure tool-specific properties.
    "customizations": {
        // Configure properties specific to VS Code.
        "vscode": {
            // Set *default* container specific settings.json values on container create.
            "settings": {
                "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "/opt/conda/bin/python"
            },
            // Add the IDs of extensions you want installed when the container is created.
            "extensions": [
                "ms-python.python",
                "ms-toolsai.jupyter",
                "ms-python.vscode-pylance",
                "mhutchie.git-graph",
                "quarto.quarto",
                "donjayamanne.githistory",
                "GitHub.vscode-pull-request-github",
                "eamodio.gitlens",
                "ms-python.isort",
                "ms-toolsai.vscode-jupyter-cell-tags",
                "ms-toolsai.vscode-jupyter-powertoys",
                "docsmsft.docs-markdown",
                "ms-python.pylint"
            ]
        }
    },
    // Use 'postCreateCommand' to run commands after the container is created.
    // "postCreateCommand": "pip3 install --user -r requirements.txt",
    // Comment out to connect as root instead. More info: https://aka.ms/vscode-remote/containers/non-root.
    "remoteUser": "data_analysis"
}
```

`Dockerfile`

```bash
FROM docker.io/mambaorg/micromamba:latest
# Create OS user
USER root
RUN deluser $MAMBA_USER
# Install additional OS packages.
# msodbc driver with Microsoft key
# curl
# r language
# unixODBC development headers
# kerberos library for debian-slim distributions

RUN apt-get update && export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    && ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends vim unzip ca-certificates \ 
    openssh-server iproute2 libcurl4-openssl-dev build-essential libxml2-dev curl \
    unixodbc-dev libgssapi-krb5-2 gnupg iputils-ping git default-jre
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add - \
    && curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/11/prod.list > \
    /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list \
    && apt-get update && export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    && ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends msodbcsql18

# Updating conda and installing mamba
RUN /bin/micromamba update -n base -c defaults conda 
    #&& /bin/micromamba update --all 

# Create OS user

ARG USERNAME=data_analysis
ARG USER_UID=1000
ARG USER_GID=$USER_UID

# Create the user
RUN groupadd --gid $USER_GID $USERNAME \
    && useradd --uid $USER_UID --gid $USER_GID -m $USERNAME \
    # [Optional] Add sudo support. Omit if you don't need to install software after connecting.
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y sudo \
    && echo $USERNAME ALL=\(root\) NOPASSWD:ALL > /etc/sudoers.d/$USERNAME \
    && chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/$USERNAME

USER $USERNAME
WORKDIR /home/data_analysis

RUN micromamba shell init --shell=bash --prefix=/opt/conda

# Copy requirements.txt (if found) to a temp location so we update the environment. Also
# copy "noop.txt" so the COPY instruction does not fail if no requirements.txt exists.
# Creating default dev environment 

COPY requirements.txt /tmp/conda-tmp/

RUN if [ -f "/tmp/conda-tmp/requirements.txt" ]; then umask 0002 \
    && /bin/micromamba create --name dev_env \
    --file /tmp/conda-tmp/requirements.txt --channel anaconda --channel conda-forge --yes; \
    fi

# Enabling conda environment to install rpy2 via pip
RUN echo "micromamba activate dev_env" >> ~/.bashrc \
    && echo "export R_HOME=/opt/conda/envs/dev_env/lib/R" >> ~/.bashrc \
    && echo "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/conda/envs/dev_env/lib/R/lib" >> ~/.bashrc \
    && echo "export PATH=$PATH:/opt/conda/envs/dev_env/bin" >> ~/.bashrc \
    && echo "export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/conda/envs/dev_env/lib/pkgconfig" >> ~/.bashrc \
    && echo "alias conda=micromamba" >> ~/.bashrc

ENV PATH=$PATH:/opt/conda/envs/dev_env/bin \
    R_HOME=/opt/conda/envs/dev_env/lib/R \
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/conda/envs/dev_env/lib/R/lib \
    PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/conda/envs/dev_env/lib/pkgconfig

# Installing the required R libraries for SPC
RUN /bin/bash --login -c "source /home/data_analysis/.bashrc;date; \
    micromamba activate dev_env;/opt/conda/envs/dev_env/bin/Rscript \
    -e \"install.packages('qicharts2',repos = 'http://cran.us.r-project.org')\";"

WORKDIR /home/data_analysis/
```